# Can't attach hose to water heater

Tags: water-heater, drain, hose

Trying to flush my electric water heater.
The flush pipe is very inconveniently located, so it's impossible to attach a hose due to the black plastic thing.
[image]

What do I do? Is there some sort of a connector I could buy ? Or should I just turn on the spigot and assume that the white pipe is a drain pipe and everything is ok?

Comment: Can't tell for sure from that angle, but you should be able to thread on a right-angle adapter then connect your hose. I wouldn't want to just open it up because then the water heater is sitting directly in a puddle of water, not the worst thing but I would avoid if possible. That tray's there to catch water in the event of the pressure release opening up.

Comment: I would prefer not using the tray for draining water.  It might be possible to turn that faucet enough to attach a hose.  Most pipe fittings have a range they will turn without causing a leak, usually greater than what you need.

Comment: They make little 45 degree hose adapters. One of them is likely to work perfectly here to get this aimed a reasonable direction for attaching a hose, and it may come in handy elsewhere in the future.

Comment: At least in my area of California, the tray is there to catch leaks; the temp/pressure release valve is required to have its own separate discharge piping to outside the house.

Comment: If you just bought a supply line for a fridge, it came with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like [this adapter from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Morvat-45-Degree-Solid-Brass-Garden-Hose-Elbow-Connector-with-On-Off-Shutoff-Valve-MOR-BELBOW-1-A/320307538) should do the trick:

[image: hose 45 adapter]

Comment: And if the black plastic tray still gets in the way, make two vertical cuts and bend down what you need for clearance for the faucet (repair as necessary after draining).  And while you have it drained, rig up whatever you need to in order to be able to do this again without cutting the tray.